# Pay per view video solution

Tags: php, video, streaming, video-streaming, pay-per-view

We are planning on building a pay per view (PPV) video solution but we have no idea from where to start. Here are the current givens:

- it will be hosted on Linux
- using PHP
- Database: MySQL

And by PPV I mean:
 - going to website, selecting a movie to watch/download
 - going to payment portal and paying
 - being now able to watch/download

So here is my question, from where to start?
is there an existing (recommended) solution that we can download/buy?

Any information would be really appreciated

Comment: This is a good example: http://movieflix.com
of course not that complex :) but something along the way

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading about someone who had a platform like this intended for adult movies that he was offering, may have even been open source. I'm sorry I forget what it was,  but even if your content is G rated, software intended for porn will probably have the features you want so I'd start looking there. It's a big industry so there has to be a few ready made solutions available.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I think It's making my search even wider now.
adding the word "porn" or "adult" to PPV and PHP is tripling the results. could you please be more specific :)

Comment: I did a little googling for you. If I was doing it I might start by looking at something like http://pandastream.com/ or maybe http://code.google.com/p/red5/ - That will at least get you started on the video streaming part of it.